# Is angular ngx-datatable server side?

Tags: angular, datatable

I'm using ngx-datatable. In my component, I'm getting 500.000 data.

Ex:  test.component.ts

```
public Rows = [
    {
      id: 1,
      mail: 'test@test.com',
      status: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      mail: 'test@test.com',
      status: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      mail: 'test@test.com',
      status: 1,
    } 
    .....
    .....
    .....
    {
     id: 500000,
     mail: 'test@test.com',
     status: 0, }
```

if I use ngx datatable and pagination, my data can be split page by page, or all data are coming just 1 time. I wondered that is my structure correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways to implement in ngx-datatable with pagination

## Server-Side pagination

ref # [server-side pagination](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#server-paging)

This requires custom logic within your frontend to get the data from the server through API call when you navigate through any pages (like for page 1 [and per page 10 data], first 1-10 data from the server, for page 2, 11-20 data)

## Client-Side pagination

ref # [client-side pagination](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#client-paging)

This feature doesn't require additional API calling, this will take all the data from the server at once and **paginate from the client side which means your data will be paginated automatically**

As you are getting 5000.000 rows at once, I believe you are using the client-side pagination in ngx-datatable. You can check the client-side pagination example here - [Code Example](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/src/app/paging/paging-client.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how to configuration to click page 1 , to click page 2, i'm not finding where is the pagination buttons

Comment: Did you go through this example?
You can get a brief idea - https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/src/app/paging/paging-client.component.ts